# Read CSV in Python with date column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to load a csv into python. Out of the 54 columns in the .csv, I definetly now that some of those are date columns.

However, after reading the csv in the python environment with pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv("foo.csv", encoding="utf-8")
```

the colums that are supposed to have dates in it, are filled with really large numbers like 997513068000, 1549627447000, 1655482531000.

I first thought that those might be ordinal dates and I can convert them to calendar dates with `datetime.fromordinal()`. However, those numbers are way to large to be ordinal dates.

Any idea on what those large numbers in the date columns mean and how I can convert them to normal dates?

Comment: The epoch time is in milliseconds format, divide the column by 1000 and try again.

Comment: @Zero dividing by 1000 won't help if using fromordinal. Should divide by 1000 and use fromtimestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almoast certainly this is an epoch time, likely in milliseconds. Use [this resource](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to easily see what it is in a normal date.

In code, use the python datetime modules fromtimestamp() to get dates from epoch

Comment: Gosh, you are so right. How did I not find this time format..